# How can I solve the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've thought about interchanging the order of summation but I don't know how and what's its rules I also have problem in solving the infinite series.

[image: series]

Comment: Interchanging the order of summation is a great idea.  Try using the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$ as long as $|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interchange the order of summation provided all the terms are nonnegative; in this case they are (this is a special case of Tonelli's theorem).

This gives

**Your sum** $ = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\dfrac{j}{j+1})^i  = \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{j}{j+2}} =  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n (j+2) = \frac{1}{2}(2n +\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)) = \frac{1}{4}n(n+5).$